# what is the purpose of the view folder in the .vim folder?

Tags: options, sessions

I got an error when opening my `.vimrc` with `vim` saying

```
".vimrc" 138L, 3781C
Error detected while processing /home/fbence/.vim/view/~=+.vimrc=:
line  117:
E518: Unknown option: termkey=
line  118:
E518: Unknown option: termsize=
```

and I saw that it is opening some file I didn't create. What is the purpose of the files here? Can I delete them? What is this "unknown option" vim found here?

I am really unsure how to tag this question, but I need to sooo.

Comment: I use `mkview` and `loadview`  for files that need re-editing, so that I can quickly pick up what's left. More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854371/vim-how-to-restore-the-cursors-logical-and-physical-positions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~/.vim/view` is a default value (under *nix) for `:h 'viewdir'` option, which, in turn, is used by the `:h :mkview` and `:h :loadview` commands.

`:mkview` is a rarely used `:mksession`-like command which saves some settings of a single window/view.